# Normalized Binary Cross Entropy for Semantic Segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am currently struggling with implementing a normalized binary cross entropy for semantic segmentation based on a normalized cross entropy in this [publication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.13554.pdf) (relevant pages are 2-3) as a custom loss function for TensorFlow/Keras.

Unfortunately, the PyTorch code given on GitHub (see code below) is not meant for semantic segmentation according to the authors comments.

```
@mlconfig.register
class NormalizedCrossEntropy(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, scale=1.0):
        super(NormalizedCrossEntropy, self).__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.scale = scale
    def forward(self, pred, labels):
        pred = F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1)
        label_one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels, self.num_classes).float().to(self.device)
        nce = -1 * torch.sum(label_one_hot * pred, dim=1) / (- pred.sum(dim=1))
        return self.scale * nce.mean()
```

A contributor on GitHub tried to implement it for semantic segmentation, also in PyTorch, but I don't know if it is correct (see code below) or this [link](https://github.com/HanxunH/Active-Passive-Losses/issues/2).

```
class NCELoss(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, ignore_label, class_weight=None):
            super(NCELoss, self).__init__()
            self.ignore_label = ignore_label
        def forward(self, pred, target, sample_weight=None):
            target = target.long()
            b, c, h, w = pred.shape
            logsoftmax = F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1)
    
            ohot = target
            mask = torch.ones_like(target).float().cuda()
            ohot[torch.where(target == self.ignore_label)] = 0
            mask[torch.where(target == self.ignore_label)] = 0
            ohot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(ohot, c).reshape(b, c, h, w).float().cuda()  # BCHW
    
            nce = (-1 * torch.sum(ohot * logsoftmax, dim=1)) / (-1 * logsoftmax.sum(dim=1))  # BHW
            nce = nce * mask  # set weights of ignore label to 0
            nce = torch.sum(nce) / target.ne(self.ignore_label).sum()  # compute mean loss
            return nce
```

Does anybody have an idea how this loss function could be correctly implemented in Tensorflow for the use of semantic segmentation with a U-Net FCN? Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: wow this normalized thing has to be famous, even though I've never heard of it before... however, try the answer that I gave at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095123/normalized-cross-entropy-loss-implementation-tensorflow-keras/73111101#73111101

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, it did not work. I guess the problem is related to the output of the fully convolutional network, which is probably not one hot encoded. When using the suggested code, I get a NaN for the loss, since it probably gets too large.